# HTML5 Download attribute on external file

Tags: javascript, html, cross-domain, greasemonkey

I am making a web app for my personal use.

I would like to set the download attribute on some links but as the file to be downloaded is on an external url, I can't get it to work.

Can you please offer me a solution, script, extension or whatever, as it is only for local and personal use.

```
<a href="http://external-site.com/movie.mp4" download="newname.mp4">video title</a>
```

thank you

Comment: - what exactly does not work?

Answer (score 0):

> In cross-origin situations, the download attribute has to be combined
>   with the Content-Disposition HTTP header, specifically with the
>   attachment disposition type, to avoid the user being warned of
>   possibly nefarious activity. (This is to protect users from being made
>   to download sensitive personal or confidential information without
>   their full understanding.)

from [W3C specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/links.html#downloading-resources)